# CiviCase Dashboard exports all cases instead of the results

Tags: civicase, export

If I start at the CiviCase dashboard, select "All Cases", then select a Status - I get the search results that I would expect. Something like all the cases of Type X that have status "Awarded"

If I select All, and then Export Cases from the Actions menu, it exports all the cases of any status or type.

The export works as expected from any other search or if I use "My Cases" from the Case Dashboard. I'm thinking this must be a bug, but I'm unsure!

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by Export? There isn't an export directly from the dashboard. There is from Find Cases but it works there if you choose status so I'm not sure which export you mean.

Comment: From the dashboard, if I click on the value for a particular award status, it takes me to a page that is more or less a search page. Here's the url:
/civicrm/case/search?reset=1&force=1&status=6&type=3&case_owner=1

This is where the Actions menu is.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Yes this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a bug. While it's picking up the status for the search the search form field for status isn't getting filled in so it gets lost on the next page for export. The url should be using case_type_id and status_type_id instead of type and status. Can you file an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/new and reference this stackexchange post?

Comment: Sure, will do. thanks!

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4126 - fixed in 5.60.0